# Restructuring the dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I received the output from my Vector AutoRegression (VAR) algorithm as a data frame and converted it into a dictionary giving me the following structure:

```
{
'Date': '2021-05-07',
 'BMI': 40.53002073252068,
 'BP': 123.00463807559225,
 'BloodSugar': 126.85415609085157,
 'ThyroidFunction': 3.0,
 'TF': 5.0
}
```

and I want to restructure it in this form :

```
# {Vital : {date : value, risk_value : 1}}
{
'BMI' : {'2021-05-07' : 40.53002073252068, risk_value : 1}, 
'BP': {'2021-05-07' : 123.00463807559225, risk_value : 1}, 
'BloodSugar' :{'2021-05-07' : 126.85415609085157, risk_value : 1}, 
'ThyroidFunction' : {'2021-05-07' : 3.0, risk_value:1}, 
'TF' : {'2021-05-07' : 5.0, risk_value:1} 
}
```

Here the "risk_value : 1" is static for now.

The only thing constant in the output from VAR in the 1st dictionary would be the 1st key- date.
The value of date will change everyday.

The Vitals(BMI, BP, BloodSugar, ThyroidFunction, TF) may vary with input with either new vitals such as (weight, height, BMI, BP, BloodSugar) or completely different vitals(cholestrolLevel, HeartRate, LDL). Like so:

```
{
 'Date': '2021-05-07',
 'weight': '170lbs',
 'height': '175cm',
 'BMI': 39.3252068004638,
 'BP': 104.530020707559225,
 'BloodSugar': 126.85415609085157,
 
}
```

I wanted to make a function which dynamically restructures the dictionary. so I tried creating a function which would take all the keys of the dictionary and tried to run it through while loop and which then creates a dictionary with vitals and the values but was unsuccessful.

I've been stuck on this for a long time and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I tried creating a function ... but was unsuccessful" -- so where's your function and what did it output?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I was unsuccessful making the function. I had this idea of taking the keys and running a while loop which would then make a dictionary but I was unable to code it, so I ended up scrapping the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_dict = {
    'Date': '2021-05-07',
    'BMI': 40.53002073252068,
    'BP': 123.00463807559225,
    'BloodSugar': 126.85415609085157,
    'ThyroidFunction': 3.0,
    'TF': 5.0
}


def parse_dict(dict_in):
    dictionary = {}
    for x in dict_in:
        if x != 'Date':
            dictionary[x] = {dict_in['Date']: dict_in[x], 'risk_value': 1}
    return dictionary


dict_out = parse_dict(your_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems @peter beat me to it but since I've already bothered...

```py
def foo(some_dict, **kwargs):
    ret = {}
    date_key = some_dict.pop('Date')
    for k, v in some_dict.items():
        ret[k] = {date_key: v}
        ret[k].update(kwargs)

    return ret


d = {
    'Date': '2021-05-07',
    'weight': '170lbs',
    'height': '175cm',
    'BMI': 39.3252068004638,
    'BP': 104.530020707559225,
    'BloodSugar': 126.85415609085157,
}

from pprint import pprint

pprint(foo(d, risk_value=42, abc='x'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
def restructure (dct):
        date = dct['Date']   #store the date 
        dct.pop('Date')   #remove 'Date' key from the dict since it not needed anymore
        for key, value in dct.items():
            dct[key] = {date:value, 'risk_value' : 1}   #update values for each key
        return dct
    
print(restructure(d))
```